# Field not updated after executing UPDATE in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to change the login password for a user using the following script:

```
<?php

#Salir si alguno de los datos no está presente
if(!isset($_POST["email"])) exit();

#Si todo va bien, se ejecuta esta parte del código...

include_once "conectar_pdo.php";

$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

/*
    Al incluir el archivo "conectar_pdo.php", todas sus variables están
    a nuestra disposición. Por lo que podemos acceder a ellas tal como si hubiéramos
    copiado y pegado el código
*/
//convertimos la pass a pass real
$encrypted_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("UPDATE tb_administradores SET
encrypted_password = ? WHERE email = ?");
$resultado = $sentencia->execute([ $encrypted_password, $email]); # Pasar en Pasar en el mismo orden de los ?


#execute regresa un booleano. True en caso de que todo vaya bien, falso en caso contrario.
#Con eso podemos evaluar

if($resultado === TRUE)  echo json_encode(array("success"=>true));
else echo json_encode(array("success"=>false));
```

Here you have the table fields

[image]

My issue is that I am getting as output from the script the response

```
{"success":true}
```

but the field encrypted_password is not updated

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check whether `$email`  contains the address you are currently looking for?

Comment: _Side note:_ Just to be picky, you're not encrypting the passwords, you're hashing them. Encrypted content can be decrypted. Hashes are only one way (you can't "de-hash" a hash). Might seem irrelevant in this case, but it really helps knowing the difference when asking questions and searching for answers going forward.

Comment: @NicoHaase, there is only one row in the table, the value for field email is modes@faro.red

Comment: You can also check if the last executed statement actually affected any rows (which would be the case if it updated a record with new data). Not sure if you're using PDO or MySQLi, but for PDO, it would be: `$sentencia->rowCount() > 0` and for MySQLi: `$sentencia->affected_rows > 0`.

Comment: FYI: This code would allow anyone to reset anyone's account as long as they know a correct mail address. Consider adding a (dynamic) token to your table which get sets when someone resets his/her password and is required to reset the password as well

Comment: So, what else did you try to resolve the problem? Having only a single row in the database does not ensure that `$email`  contains exactly that value

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since you have the condition `WHERE email = ?` and the row is not updated, it would mean that the row does not exist.

The result would be `{success:true}` because the query did succeed, there were no errors.

The value in `$email` does not match what is stored.  Debug it and display the value,